# What does Java compare, when comparing char, Unicode or ASCII code?

Tags: java, char

For example, `char hello='a'` and `char hello2='b'`

Now I make
`if (hello<hello2) ...`

In the if, it is true, but what does Java compares, the Unicode or ASCII code?

Comment: Please add more code and `char hello2 = 'b'` not double quotes

Comment: unicode is the same as standard ascii for codes `00` through `7F`. Beyond that, standard ascii doesn't apply.

Comment: See [Java Tutorial Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html): _"**`char`**: The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of `'\u0000'` (or 0) and a maximum value of `'\uffff'` (or 65,535 inclusive)."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer values are compared.  Chars are 2 bytes long, so the 2 byte value will be checked.

It's basically UTF-16.  The reason for this is when Java came out, we had just decided ASCII wasn't good enough, but didn't realize that we needed the number of characters we do.  We thought going from 8 to 16 bits would be enough.  It wasn't, but by the time UTF-8 won out, it was way too late to change.